# Selecting entities based on first character of field being a letter using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, query, function

I would like to select entities whose addresses are incomplete, i.e. the first character is a letter instead of being a number. Does QGIS have an "is numeric" -type function to accomplish this?

Not Is Numeric (left("ADDRESS",'1') )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily using a regular expression match. Try using the expression:

```
regexp_match( "ADDRESS", '^[A-Za-z].*')
```

This will select all records where the ADDRESS field begins with an upper or lowercase letter. The second argument is a regular expression - it specifies that the string has to begin '^' with a character in the range '[A-Za-z]', and this can be followed by any other combination of character '.*'. Regular expressions can be tricky to get your head around at first, but they are VERY powerful for tasks like this.

Comment: Would be nice if the query box (for subsetting) supported reg expressions too, but was more flexible and could make use of [reg exp operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE).

Comment: I am using QGIS and I wonder if I could restrict the insertion to be just with these characters **(N,M,F,L and C)**. I've tried ```regexp_match(  "Project" , '[N,M,F,L,C]')``` but the result was anything with the characters **(N,M,F,L and C)** will work. but only the characters **(N,M,F,L and C)** should be inserted in the field.